# Django Import/Export in a table where foreign key is a string - constantly throws an error Column 'system': invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django

I have explored a lot of examples of **Django export/import**. 
When I try importing in a table with a foreign key with datatype string, I get this error - `invalid literal for int() with base 10`, which I understand because the foreign key field has datatype `int`.

But for that before importing, do I have to edit the column in my csv with integer `id` values of the column being looked up for translating the foreign key value? Please share any working examples, I want to use a column of datatype string as foreign key and not the integer.

csv contains data like below:-

```
host_name,server_type,bay_location,ip
abc,virtual,abc,127.0.0.1
```

models.py

```
class TypeOfServer(models.Model):
 type= models.CharField(unique=True)

class Server(models.Model)
 host_name = models.Charfield()
 server_type = 
 models.ForeignKey('TypeOfServer',to_field='type',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 bay_location= models.Charfield()
 ip= models.Charfield()
```

admin.py
    class ServerResource(resources.ModelResource):

```
class Meta:
  model = Server
  server_type = fields.Field(
  column_name='server_type',attribute='server_type',
  widget=ForeignKeyWidget(TypeOfServer,'type'))
  fields = ('host_name','server_type','bay_location','ip')
  skip_unchanged = True
  report_skipped = False
```

When I try importing the csv, it has string in the column server_type, but actually the datatype of server_type created in table in Server is int since its a foreign key. How to deal with this?

Comment: kindly consider adding more information , e.g. the part of the code that is creating issues

Comment: I just updated the explanation with code

Comment: I got it working. Keeping the ForeignWidget columns ouside the Meta class worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without an example it would be difficult to tell the exact issue. But from what you have posted. I guess the problem you are facing is you have the `id` value as floating number.

```
int('55063.000000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '55063.000000'
```

To solve it you can do something like this

```
int(float('55063.000000'))  
55063
```

Comment: Please look at the explanation of the problem. I have updated it with the code.